# Why are only mutable variables accessible in nested functions?

Tags: python, nested, closures, mutable

here is a simple (useless) function:

```
def f(x):
    b = [x]
    def g(a):
        b[0] -= 1
        return a - b[0]
    return g
```

it works fine. let's change it a tiny bit:

```
def f(x):
    b = x
    def g(a):
        b -= 1
        return a - b
    return g
```

Now it gives an error saying that b is undefined! Sure, it can be solved using `nonlocal`, but I'd like to know why does this happen in the first place? Why are mutables accessable and immutables aren't?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221236/discussion-on-question-by-bendaman-why-are-only-mutable-variables-accessible-in).

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it has nothing to do with mutable or immutable (the language does not know whether a type is "mutable" or not). The difference here is because you are assigning to the variable in one case and just reading from it in the other case.

In your second example, the line `b -= 1` is the same as `b = b - 1`. The fact you are assigning to the variable `b` makes a local variable named `b`, separate from the outside variable named `b`. Since the local variable `b` has not been assigned to when evaluating the right side of the assignment, reading from the local `b` there is an error.

In your first example, the line `b[0] -= 1` is the same as `b[0] = b[0] - 1`. But that is not a variable assignment. That is just a list element access. It is just syntactic sugar for `b.__setitem__(0, b.__getitem__(0) - 1)`. You are not assigning to the variable `b` here -- all you're doing is reading from the variable `b` two times (in order to call methods on the object it points to). Since you are only reading from `b`, it uses the external variable `b`.

If in the first example, with your mutable list, you did a variable assignment like you did in the second example, it would equally create a local variable, and the reading of that local variable before assignment would also not work:

```
def f(x):
    b = [x]
    def g(a):
        b = [b[0] - 1]
        return a - b[0]
    return g
```